# 404 Error: ENOENT, stat '/public/ when starting app from grunt

Tags: express, routes, gruntjs

I'm runnig an express app that attempts to serve static html using sedfile

```
res.sendfile('/public/testform.html');
```

When I start the app with node app.js it works correctly. when I try and use grunt to start the app, it does not work, it gives me the error

404 Error: ENOENT, stat '/public/testform.html'

I have tried both

```
  res.sendfile(__dirname+'/public/testform.html');
  res.sendfile(path.resolve('/public/testform.html'));
```

but I still have no luck from grunt. What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why but the only way i was able to get this to work was the following

```
app.get('/testform', function (req, res) {
  var correctPath = path.join(__dirname, '..','/public/testform.html');
  res.sendfile(daPath);
});
```

__dirname inside routes is one level below where it should have been, so I had to move up one level.

Answer (score 0):

Might be something to do with express static file serve.

Just add this into your app.js:

```
app.use('/public',express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'path-to-public/public')));
```

Please note by **app** i am referring to : `var app = express();` and do take care of the order of the middle wares.